# Can't change the height of the Chrome developer tools Certificate view

Tags: google-chrome

Is it able to change the height of the certificate information in Google Chrome? I can only change the width.

[image]

And here is the view, when I dont use the Fullscreensize of the browser

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the same problem on macOS Sierra with Chrome 53.x. I've just upgraded to Chrome 54 and it resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Thats the solution.